# Error: "The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection" when adding a Parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a few similar functions that interact with my SQL server (selects, calls to stored procdures etc.) and all work with the exception of the one below.  Each `SqlConnection` is contained within a using block with the `SqlCommand` also contained within a using block.

This code is failing when attempting to add the `@LastUpdated` parameter. I've tried some suggestions I've seen in other posts: `cmd.Parameters.Clear()`, wrapping in using, etc., but no luck. A few posts with the same error were resolved when duplicate attempts to set the same parameter where found. It's possible I'm missing that but I've looked over this for a few hours, even cleaned the glasses. Any direction would be appreciated.

```
private void _AddCartItem(bool hasEventInCart, _EventCart cartContents, ref int cartItemId)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_striMISConnection))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            // add/update CartItem
            if (hasEventInCart)
            {
                // Update item
                cmd.CommandText = "SProc2Insert @CartItemId, @ID, 'Event', @Created, @LastUpdated";
                param.ParameterName = "@CartItemId";
                param.Value = cartItemId;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            }
            else
            {
                // add item
                cmd.CommandText = "SProc2Update @ID, 'Event', @Created, @LastUpdated";
            }

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            param.ParameterName = "@Created";
            param.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            param.ParameterName = "@LastUpdated";
            param.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            **cmd.Parameters.Add(param);**

            param.ParameterName = "@ID";
            param.Value = this.ID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            if (hasEventInCart)
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // do the update
            }
            else
            {
                cartItemId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                foreach (var currentCartEvent in cartContents.CartEvents)
                {
                    if (currentCartEvent.EventCode == this.EventCode)
                    {
                        currentCartEvent.CartItemID = cartItemId;
                    }
                }
            }
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create new SqlParameter instances, not reuse the same one. They're passed by reference. You're overwriting it. As a result when you call add again you're trying to add a parameter that already exists since you updated the name of the first one. They're the same object.

Comment: Create new instance of your SqlParameter or make IEnumerable<SqlParameter> then cmd.Parameters.AddRange

Comment: Tips: Adding a parameter and setting the value may be done in a single statement: `sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Filename", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 64).Value = "Foo";`. Adding `output` or `returnvalue` parameters may be done in a single statement: `sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Filename", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 64).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;`. It's a bit odd that you are passing `DateTime` values as strings rather than `DateTime` or a more suitable data type (`Date`, `DateTimeOffset`, ... .).

Comment: @HABO ... thanks for the shortcut.  This is a first pass on the function.  I'll clean it up and adjust the DateTime values.

Answer (score 4):

**I had the same problem, you can solve it with the code below:**

```
if (SqlParams != null && SqlParams.Count > 0)
{ 
    foreach (SqlParameter spp in SqlParams )
    {
        SqlParameter nameParam = new SqlParameter(spp.ParameterName, spp.SqlValue);

        mycmd.Parameters.Add(nameParam);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you're calling a stored procedure, you need to set your `CommandType` to `CommandType.StoredProcedure` - not `Text` :

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

and just use the stored procedure name as your command query:

```
cmd.CommandText = "dbo.SProc2Update";
```

Second, I wouldn't use just a single `SqlParameter` instance and keep adding that over and over again - I would just use the `.Add()` method directly - and **stop converting** all date/time to string! Use the **appropriate** native datatype they have - `DateTime` - and specify as such in your `Parameters.Add()` call:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Created", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastUpdated", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: he's calling a sproc using an ad-hoc query though. he can't just directly change `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure`, the author would need to drop the parameter list. The author needs to pass 'Event' as a parameter as well if he were to change the command type.

Comment: thank you both for the replies.  The earlier responses did resolve the issue however your suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got this working:

```
        ILease lease = (ILease)_SqlParameterCollection.InitializeLifetimeService();
        if (lease.CurrentState == LeaseState.Initial)
        {
            lease.InitialLeaseTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            lease.SponsorshipTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
            lease.RenewOnCallTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
            lease.Renew(new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0));
```